# How to redirect two url to the same file with .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, multilingual

Here's my problem, I have a bilingual website nd I don't know how to manage the urls.

I would like

- **mydomain.tld/contact-us** and **mydomain.tld/nous-contacter** to show **contact-us.php**
- **mydomain.tld/pricing** and **mydomain.tld/prix** to show **pricing.php**
- **mydomain.tld/pricing/item1** and **mydomain.tld/prix/item1** to show **pricing.php?what=item1** (for this one I'm not sure how to handle that, any hint is appreciate).

I can do the case one and two with ease with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ $1.php [R] # R for debug, make sure it shows the right page
```

But I don't want to have 10 entries for 5 pages, and this is not a secure way.

It would be great if (maybe) I can do something like: (contact-us|nous-contacter) as a condition. Still not sure if this is possible and if it is, if its the easiest and most secure way to do it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(contact-us|nous-contacter)$ contact-us.php [R]
RewriteRule ^(pricing|prix)$ pricing.php [R]
RewriteRule ^(pricing|prix)/(.*)$ pricing.php?what=$2 [R]
```

Comment: Well, it's easier when you know how it's working :P  Thank you very much nachito :)